# How to access Object inside Object (JSON) in UI5

Tags: json, sapui5

I have the JSON data with the structure like this :

```
0: Object
  Folder: Object
  NodeId: Object
  NodeLevel: Object
  Nodetype: Object
  NodeText: Object
  ...
```

If I expand these nodes again it contains #text: data.

```
0: Object
  Folder: Object
  NodeId: Object
  NodeLevel: Object
    #text: "07"
  Nodetype: Object
  NodeText: Object
    #text: "[Exploratory] Translation of the document in the RIA"
  ...
```

I want to display these data on a table of SAPUI5. This is my code :

```
   var oCol;
    oCol = new sap.ui.table.Column({
        label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Test Plan"}),
        template: new sap.ui.commons.TextView().bindProperty("text", "#text"),
        width: "450px",
        resizable : false
    });
    oTable.addColumn(oCol);
```

And I binding the data like this :

```
   var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
    oModel.setData(myGTP);
    oTable.setModel(oModel);
    oTable.bindRows("/NodeText");
```

In this case, I want to see the text under NodeText node.
But I cannot reach the data that I want. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsbin.com/suce/1/edit?html,output

Not totally sure if I reflected your model correctly.

If your model contains hierarchical data you could use a TreeTable for visualization. If you want to display it in a flat table your data needs to be flat as well. Aggregation Bindings are only possible against arrays inside of your JSON data.